# mailing list for local conferences

Tags: conference

Often I learn about conferences, even in my own country, when it is too late to submit papers. Is there a mailing list, or another way to get information about conferences in a specific location and domain?

EDIT: I am mainly interested in computer science and game theory.

Comment: Many fields have mailing lists (listservers) to distribute information. To help you,it would therefore be necessary to know your specialization or general field. There is no service that would safely provide information for all research fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use http://www.conferencealerts.com/ to locate academic conferences in your desired country. These listings are sorted by a **topic or country** which you can select on the first page. Once chosen you will get a list of the various conferences **organized by month**. Moreover, you have the option of subscribing and thus receiving **email announcements** about those events.

Comment: [ConfSearch](http://www.confsearch.org/confsearch/) does something similar for Computer Science conferences.

Answer (score 7):

There is a wiki devoted to call for papers (http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/).

Googling can help you find earlier editions of conferences and so forth. Make a list of the ones relevant for you and when they occur – each edition of a conference will occur at the same time of year. Keep this list on your wall, perhaps sorted by month of conference (or better, month of deadline). Google will help find the current edition.

Comment: +1 for creating a calendar list sorted by month of deadline

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [www.tjdb.org/CFP](http://www.tjdb.org/CFP)

it will provide all upcoming events(journals, conference, seminars, workshop, sessions). subscribe to its rss feed with particular keyword. and you can also post new academic events.

Comment: That link doesn't seem to provide the information mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to keep a spreadsheet of all the relevant conferences, with columns for the next submission deadline, conference URL, organisation, and organisation URL.

When I find out about a conference too late to submit, I still add it to my spreadsheet. I try to find out if the conference is annual, every two years, or what. I put down a rough guess for the next submission deadline based on the current deadline. That way I'm prepared for the following year.

Also, when I read a paper in my field, I always note where it was published (because the journal or conference might be suitable for my own work). If it's a conference, I add it to my spreadsheet with as much info as I can find.

This is in addition to looking for appropriate mailing lists, as the other answers have covered.